# backward compatibility for (interactive "^") in Emacs 22

Tags: emacs, elisp, compatibility, backwards-compatibility

In Emacs 23 and 24, the following works fine:

```
(defun foo (&optional arg)
  (interactive "^p")
  (message "arg is %i" arg))
```

In Emacs 22, I get the following error:

> `` Invalid control letter `^' (136) in interactive calling string ``

I tried this:

```
(defun foo (&optional arg)
  (interactive (concat (if (> emacs-major-version 22) "^" "") "p"))
  (message "arg is %i" arg))
```

but I get:

> `Wrong type argument: listp, "^p"`

What is the best way to use `^` in Emacs 23 or 24 but not in Emacs 22?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a macro that expands to a `defun`, where the `interactive` form would start with a `^` if shift selection is supported. For example:

```
(defmacro my-defun (name args doc inter &rest body)
  "Like `defun' but enables shift selection, if supported.

Note that the documentation string and the `interactive' form
must be present. Requires a string literal as argument to
`interactive'.

See `this-command-keys-shift-translated' for the meaning of shift
translation.

This is implemented by adding the `^' token to the `interactive'
string, when shift selection is supported."
  `(defun ,name ,args
     ,doc
     ,(progn
        (assert (stringp doc))
        (assert (listp inter))
        (assert (eq (length inter) 2))
        (assert (eq (car inter) 'interactive))
        (let ((s (nth 1 inter)))
          (assert (stringp s))
          (if (fboundp 'handle-shift-selection)
              (setq s (concat "^" s)))
          (list 'interactive s)))
     ,@body))
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you would need to do something like

```
(interactive
  (progn
    (when (fboundp 'handle-shift-selection)
      (handle-shift-selection))
    (list (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg))))
```

If the argument to `interactive` is not a `string`, it should evaluate to a list (remember that `interactive` is *not* a function, it is a special form).

Comment: Indeed, tho better use `(fboundp 'handle-shift-selection)` instead of `(> emacs-major-version 22)`.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid reimplementing what `(interactive)` does for me?  I'd rather not have to figure out how to reimplement `(interactive "^NEnter a number: ")`.  Looking at [the Emacs source for `call-interactively`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/callint.c?id=EMACS_22_3#n692) I'm guessing there's no way.

Comment: @Stefan: if emacs had read-time conditionals, it would have been even easier: `#+handle-shift-selection "^p" #-handle-shift-selection "p"`